# Calculate HANA global allocation limit

Tags: hana

How can I calculate the global_allocation_limit parameter? When I have SAP Netweaver and SAP HANA DB installed on a server. And the current database size in RAM is 300 GB.

Many thanks

Comment: You need to include what you have tried, and what happened, Like did you get an error, or is the code you expected to work not working. Its really hard to say what to do when we don't know what you have done wrong. The point of stack overflow is to offer solutions, not to write code for someone.

Answer (score 3):

As you correctly mentioned, the Global Allocation Limit is a parameter, which can be set by the administrator. If the administrator has set this to an arbitrary value, there is no way for you to "calculate" it.

However, if your question is referring to the default value, the [official documentation](https://help.sap.com/docs/SAP_HANA_PLATFORM/6b94445c94ae495c83a19646e7c3fd56/c1a774b3bb571014af018d2352f0d757.html?locale=en-US) may be helpful:

> The default value is 0 in which case the global allocation limit is
> calculated as follows: 90% of the first 64 GB of available physical
> memory on the host plus 97% of each further GB. Or, in the case of
> small physical memory, physical memory minus 1 GB.